# Custom context hook TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to use a custom hook with the context API based on this interesting approach [todos-many-ways](https://github.com/jherr/todos-many-ways/blob/master/todo-customhook/src/store.tsx)

I am getting an error when using it with a simple state for a number, ideally I would have a more meaningful setter function but I am getting errors just setting it up.

```
import * as React from 'react'

const mainState = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState<number | null>(null)

  return {
    edit,
    clear: () => setEdit(null)
  }
}

const MainContext = () => React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof mainState> | null>(null)

// I get an error on `MainContext`: `...is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<unknown>`
export const useMainContext = () => React.useContext(MainContext)

export function MainProvider({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}){
  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={mainState()}>
      {children}
    </MainContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why not `MainContext = React.createContext`, why you pass a function?

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the value instead of declaring a function:

```
const MainContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof mainState> | null>(null)
```